# c++ multiple copy assignment operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

I'm studying C++ and I have a question regarding assignment operators.

Based on what is written here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment, it seems that

> ...a class can have multiple copy assignment operators, e.g. both T&
> T::operator=(const T &) and T& T::operator=(T).

I tried to make a class with both operators but I don't see where I'm wrong, because I get the this from the compiler:

> error C2593: 'operator =' ambiguous*

This is the class:

```
class Point2D
{
public:
    Point2D(); // default constructor
    Point2D(double xValue, double yValue); // overloaded constructor
    Point2D(const Point2D& ref); // copy constructor const
    Point2D(Point2D& ref); // copy constructor for copy and swap
    Point2D(Point2D&& moveRef); // move constructor

    ~Point2D(); // destructor

    Point2D& operator=( const Point2D& other ); // copy assignment operator const
    Point2D& operator=( Point2D other ); // copy assignment operator for copyAndSwap
private:
    double x;
    double y;

    int *ptr;
};
```

This is where it gives me the error:

```
void copy_assign_test()
{
    cout << endl << "Copy assign" << endl;

    Point2D a(1, 1);
    Point2D b(2, 2);
    
    Point2D c(3, 3);
    Point2D& ptRef = c;
    Point2D d(6, 6);

    a = ptRef; // error: ambiguous operator
    b = a; // // error: ambiguous operator
    d = Point2D(7,7); // error: ambiguous operator
}
```

My question concerns the following:

- Why is `a=ptRef` ambiguous if `ptRef` is a reference?
- Why is `b=a` is ambiguous if `a` isn't declared as reference?
- Why is `d = Point2D(7,7)` ambiguous if `Point2D(7,7)` isn't a reference?

All my tests compiled using Visual Studio 2019, with the C++17 standard.

Comment: The quote is on cppref, but I'm not sure where the standard says so. Intuitively it doesn't make sense to allow such an overload.

Comment: You've found a flaw in the documentation you link to.   A class `T` cannot simultaneously have both a `operator=(T)` and an `operator=(const T &)` since there is no way to distinguish between them in calling code.   i.e. ambiguity.    It is possible to overload based on arguments that are `const` and non-`const` references but, practically, the uses for that are rare.

Comment: Even worse, a `T& T::operator=(T)` doesn't make sense because it will create a copy before calling the operator. In fact, C++ doesn't recognise such a function as copy assignment.

Comment: @bitmask it is a valid copy assignment operator and useful for avoiding declaring a separate copy and move assignment operator

Comment: @AlanBirtles What am I doing wrong [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dnG6Wh), then?

Comment: @bitmask as stated in the warning you need to define the copy constructor too: https://godbolt.org/z/P8fvfa, the assignment, creates a temporary copy so needs a copy constructor

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah thanks. My mental parser mistook that `S::S` for a `S::operator=` which of course would have been the important thing to look out for. Sorry for that. Btw. I found the section in the standard that allows this. I still don't think this is a good idea but it's in the standard.

Comment: @Gianluca Ah, sorry. It was in the section about implicitly declared operators, where it doesn’t belong.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are right in this case the operators are not implicitly declared. cppreference should review this page better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you cite derives its statement from the C++ standard's `[class.copy]` (C++14) / [`[class.copy.assign]` (C++17)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf#subsection.15.8.2) section:

> 15.8.2  Copy/move assignment operator
>
> 1. A user-declared copy assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static
>    non-template member function of class X with ***exactly one parameter of
>    type X,X&,const X&***,volatile X& or const volatile X&.<sup>121</sup>[Note: An
>    overloaded assignment operator must be declared to have only one
>    parameter; see 16.5.3.— end note] ***[Note:More than one form of copy
>    assignment operator may be declared for a class.— end note]***

(emphasis added)

So, the documentation you cite is correct, although it refers to a *Note* in the standard. [Edit: snip]

### Why doesn't it compile if the standard allows it?

After stating which arguments are allowed and that overloads are allowed, the standard doesn't have to also state which combinations are (in-)valid because that would mean repeating itself. Overload resolution regulations (and by virtue of it, ambiguity and conflict rules) are outlined in the lengthy `[over.match]` section 16.3 with its 20 pages.

Comment: The standard allows you to declare both, it doesn't say that you can actually use a class that has both declared? It makes no sense for it to be that way but I'm sure there's a good reason for the note?

Comment: I suppose having both `X&` and `const X&` would be a usable combination

Comment: @AlanBirtles Absolutely. But I think now the standard doesn't *have* to state outright which combinations are invalid, because it already has a list in 16.3.1. about which overloads exist and it *somewhere* states that the overload mustn't be ambiguous. As `T` and `T const&` are ambiguous, it's implicitly forbidden. However, although the standard can get away with such a thing, the cppref documentation should make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

`a = ptRef;` is ambig function call because `ptRef` can be passed by ref or value to a const arg or not const arg.
In all of your cases the assignments matches both patterns.
Anyway I don't see why  `Point2D& operator=( Point2D other );` operator is required when `Point2D& operator=( const Point2D& other );` is implemented.

Comment: The question is tagged `language-lawyer`. It's not a question about if the code makes sense. It's a question about the spcific rules of the language.

Comment: There is no why, it was just to understand the difference between the two overloads and if they could coexist in the same class.